Random whitespace while trying to jwt auth for salesforce using ant via Jenkins
While trying to execute this ant script via Jenkins in ubuntu
<exec executable="sf" failonerror="true">
                <arg value="org"/>
                <arg value="login"/>
                <arg value="jwt"/>
                <arg value="-i ${clientId}"/>
                <arg value="-f ${jwtKeyFile}"/>
                <arg value="-o ${sfsb.username}"/>
                <arg value="-r ${sfsb.instanceurl}"/>
                <arg value="--json"/>
</exec>

where ${jwtKeyFile} = certificate/server.key
getting this error error while running the build
this script works fine for windows its tested there but we need to implement it on ubuntu there the path to Jenkins workspace its adding a random whitespace which results in build failure
